# Rails.cache throws "marshal dump" error when changed from memory store to memcached store

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I set this in my environment

```
config.action_controller.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
```

`ActionController::Base.cache_store` will use a memcached store but Rails.cache will use a memory store instead:

```
$ ./script/console
>> ActionController::Base.cache_store
=> #<ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore:0xb6eb4bbc @data=<MemCache: 1 servers, ns: nil, ro: false>>
>> Rails.cache
=> #<ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore:0xb78b5e54 @data={}>
```

In my app, I use `Rails.cache.fetch(key){ object }` to cache objects inside my helpers. All this time, I assumed that `Rails.cache` uses the memcached store so I'm surprised that it uses memory store.

If I change the `cache_store` setting in my environment to

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
```

both ActionController::Base.cache_store and Rails.cache will now use the same memory store, which is what I expect:

```
$ ./script/console
>> ActionController::Base.cache_store
=> #<ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore:0xb7b8e928 @data=<MemCache: 1 servers, ns: nil, ro: false>, @middleware=#<Class:0xb7b73d44>, @thread_local_key=:active_support_cache_mem_cache_store_local_cache>
>> Rails.cache
=> #<ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore:0xb7b8e928 @data=<MemCache: 1 servers, ns: nil, ro: false>, @middleware=#<Class:0xb7b73d44>, @thread_local_key=:active_support_cache_mem_cache_store_local_cache>
```

However, when I run the app, I get a "marshal dump" error in the line where I call `Rails.cache.fetch(key){ object }`

```
no marshal_dump is defined for class Proc

Extracted source (around line #1): 
1: Rails.cache.fetch(fragment_cache_key(...), :expires_in => 15.minutes) { ... }

vendor/gems/memcache-client-1.8.1/lib/memcache.rb:359:in 'dump'
vendor/gems/memcache-client-1.8.1/lib/memcache.rb:359:in 'set_without_newrelic_trace'
```

What gives? Is `Rails.cache` meant to be a memory store? Should I call `controller.cache_store.fetch` in the places where I call `Rails.cache.fetch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot marshal objects that have procs or lambdas in them. It's a current limitation of the Ruby interpreter. What exactly are you storing in the cache? Whole objects? Or just IDs? Show me what you're storing in the cache and someone can help you figure it out.

Comment: Hi Salil. Yeah, the object had some procs stored inside. It worked before because Rail.cache was using memory store instead of memcache store.